# python 2.7 - pip install -> Errno 42

Tags: python-2.7, pip

last week i had to reset my PC.
And today I'm trying to install some packages with python 2.7 (Don't ask why or tell me to upgrade cause i can't)

```
|ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence
```

Any suggestion how to solve it?

I can add -q (and its work) but i have about 40 packages to install.
I Already check my environment variable, and everything seem OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should install or export UTF first,
So in your command window

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

like this
and you can also use

import sys /n
reload(sys) /n
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

Note that setting the default encoding using sys.setdefaultencoding() is not recommended in Python 2.7, as it can have unintended side effects. It's better to explicitly encode/decode strings using the encode() and decode() methods, or use libraries like six that provide compatibility between Python 2 and 3.

But you try both and later reach if any quarries.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you!!
For future purpose here YouTube video explain how to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCSPIoAWCT4